# EMDK installation does not see Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, motorola-emdk

I downloaded Android Studio 2.3.2 and am trying to install the EMDK v6.3 (problem is for other versions as well) and the install wizard is telling me that Android Studio has not been installed on this computer. I am trying to figure out why this is so.

Answer (score 0):

That is a known issue with EMDK and Android Studio 2.3 unfortunately.  There is a patch available at https://developer.zebra.com/community/android/android-forums/android-blogs/blog/2017/03/15/android-studio-23-emdk-for-android-beta-fix for EMDK 6.3